# How do I disable a Googletest (gtest) parametrized test?

Tags: c++, googletest

Googletest (GTest) allows you to disable individual tests by adding

> *DISABLED_*

prefix to the test name.

What about parametrized tests -- how do I disable those? Adding the prefix to the test name does not disable them.

For example, how do I disable the example test provided by GTest [documentation](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#value-parameterized-tests):

```
class FooTest : public ::testing::TestWithParam<const char*> {
  // You can implement all the usual fixture class members here.
  // To access the test parameter, call GetParam() from class
  // TestWithParam<T>.
};

TEST_P(FooTest, HasBlahBlah) {
  ...
}

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(InstantiationName,
                        FooTest,
                        ::testing::Values("meeny", "miny", "moe"));
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to add the

> *DISABLED_*

prefix to the instantiation name, like this:

```
INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(DISABLED_InstantiationName,
                        FooTest,
                        ::testing::Values("meeny", "miny", "moe"));
```